# Can I use MariaDB ColumnStore with Django (Django-ORM)?

Tags: django, mariadb, django-orm, columnstore

I have a Django project which uses MariaDB (engine - django.db.backends.mysql). I would like to user MariaDB ColumnStore instead - is it possible? Will I need a different ORM engine?

Also, I develop on Windows 10 Pro PC and plan to set up ColumnStore using docker containers provided by MariaDB. This should not be an issue, right?

Thank you

Comment: Will you be using any SQL syntax that is unique to ColumStore, other than the `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: I don't think so. My plan is to use ColumnStore to improve performance, since my system deals with mostly heavy ianalytical queries on one or just a few number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do it - it works, and performance seems to be better